# Error stating can't convert 'char' to 'string'

Tags: c#

```
const char * path=@"C:\Documents and Settings\QI_3664\Desktop\senthur.prt";
```

this is the line which is giving the problem.

At first it reported that escape sequence is missing, later when I added the `@` symbol it started reporting that 'char' can't be converted to'string'

Pls someone help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

The same line works well in c++. I compiled both the programs in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: There's no need for a pointer like this (I'm surprised Visual Studio didn't give you an "Unsafe code" error). Just store it in a string.

Comment: You very rarely will need to use pointers in a managed language like C#.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you should use `string` (in this case):

```
const string path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\QI_3664\Desktop\senthur.prt";
```

Note that C# supports pointers in a limited manner, they requires `unsafe` context. You can read more @[MSDN: Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx). Also you may find this useful: @[MSDN: Comparison Between C++ and C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that,                                                  This is the syntax for the function for which the path was mentioned "constchar" .                                                          Now how will I supply the path if you say c# accepts value only in "string" type                                         int UF_PART_new ( const char * part_name, int units, tag_t * part )

Comment: I didn't say that C# accepts only `string` values, but if you want to pass it as function parameter then you need to do something like this `int func(string path)`

Comment: what does mean by unsafe context in complier error ? Sorry for troubling but I'm a novice programmer !

Comment: You could read about this via MSDN link in my answer, you can also read more @[MSDN Pointer types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) and @[MSDN: unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(v=vs.71).aspx)